# MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com/sun/rowset/RowSetResourceBundle (SBT project)

Tags: scala, jdbc, intellij-idea, sbt

Running `sbt test` via console (v0.13.1 on Windows) throws a `MissingResourceException: : Can't find bundle for base name com/sun/rowset/RowSetResourceBundle, locale en_CA` when I try to create an instance of `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` object.  The same code runs great if I use IntelliJ to run a Specs test; it only fails when trying to run via SBT console.

Here is the specs2 test I'm trying to run:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.SpecificationWithJUnit
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl

class DatabaseTest extends SpecificationWithJUnit {
  "CachedRowSet Test" should {
    "Create a new CachedRowSetImpl instance" in {
      val rowSet: CachedRowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl()
      rowSet must_!= null
    }
  }
}
```

And the resulting exception:

```
[error] MissingResourceException: : Can't find bundle for base name com/sun/rowset/RowSetResourceBundle, locale en_CA  (null:-1)
[error] com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.<init>(Unknown Source)
[error] com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.getJdbcRowSetResourceBundle(Unknown Source)
[error] com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
[error] test.DatabaseTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DatabaseTest.scala:10)
[error] test.DatabaseTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DatabaseTest.scala:9)
```

Update: `build.sbt` contents:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6", "-Xlint:deprecation", "-Xlint:unchecked")

libraryDependencies in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4" withSources(),
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.7" withSources()
)

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
```

Comment: How does build configuration look like - `build.sbt` or `project/*.scala` files? It'd be great if you update the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when running ScalaTest using SBT. In IntelliJ the tests ran clean but in SBT the late bound implementation for CachedRowSet did not get resolved and the following exception was thrown,

> MissingResourceException: : Can't find bundle for base name
>   com/sun/rowset/RowSetResourceBundle, locale en_GB

The problem appears to be that the SBT thread does not resolve run time class loads back to the JVM (the missing resources are provided by rt.jar and resources.jar).
This can be fixed by forcing the SBT thread to fork new threads for each test by putting the following instruction into the main body of the SBT build file,

```
fork in Test := true
```

Comment: I cannot afford to fork in Test := true due to other issues I have, any other idea? I am stuck with this, thxs in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CachedRowSetImpl is an internal class in some version of the JDK runtime but is not officially part of the JDK. You can tell it is internal because its package starts with "com.sun", not "java". It's likely that your Windows machine has a completely different JDK that lacks this internal class.

I highly recommend avoiding the use of "com.sun" classes and find the idiomatic way to get the job done with the existing JDK.

Comment: My JDK runtime has the CachedRowSetImpl, and jre/lib/resources.jar contains the correct resource files.  IntelliJ IDEA has no problem running the code, while SBT throws exception.
Also, com.sun.* packages are not internal - sun.* packages are (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html); they are reference Oracle implementations of Java interfaces.  Using them is perfectly fine, with the understanding that you need Oracle JDK to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use **Java 7**...

As of Java 7 there're few [classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html) and [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetFactory.html#createCachedRowSet%28%29) that shield you from errors like yours. Develop against interfaces (with some help from providers) and life becomes easier.

```
import org.specs2.mutable.SpecificationWithJUnit
import javax.sql.rowset._

class DatabaseTest extends SpecificationWithJUnit {
  "CachedRowSet Test" should {
    "Create a new CachedRowSetImpl instance" in {
      val rsf = RowSetProvider.newFactory
      val rowSet: CachedRowSet = rsf.createCachedRowSet
      rowSet must_!= null
    }
  }
}
```

With the Specs2 test, `test` worked fine for me.

```
> test
[info] DatabaseTest
[info]
[info] CachedRowSet Test should
[info] + Create a new CachedRowSetImpl instance
[info]
[info] Total for specification DatabaseTest
[info] Finished in 41 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
```

BTW: The missing resources are in `lib/resources.jar` in JRE, but couldn't figure out why they're reported as missing (even when they ended up in `lib` directory of a project).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Not in Scala, but Java.

`com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetResourceBundle` loads resource with context classloader.

In my case context classloader is a `URLClassLoader`.

And it looks like a really weird limitation of `URLClassLoader` - when looking for resources it does not consult parent classloader, it checks only its own URLs list.

Hope that helps.